# How to find .ssh private and public keys

Tags: git, bash, ssh, key, rsa

I have been trying to connect bitbucket to my local git repository but having hard time finding private and public keys.

I am generating .ssh keys from this command in bash

```
$ ssh keygen -t rsa

Generating public/private rsa key pairs
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/TOSHIBA/.ssh/id_rsa):    password.txt (I don't have password.txt file on my system it was random file name I provided) 

Enter passphrase(empty for no passphrase): (I left empty)
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in password.txt.
You public key has been saved in password.txt.pub
The key fingerprint is:
9c:9e:07:63:45:ad:76:b3:d0:e1:e1:0f:6c:20:aa:c4 TOSHIBA@TOSHIBA-PC
The Key's random art image is
```

I am not able to find out keys generated. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The private key is in your file `password.txt` and the public key is in `password.txt.pub`.  The full path depends on your current working directory in the shell.

You could have just pressed enter instead of the file name.  Then ssh-keygen would have saved it to the default file name `/c/Users/TOSHIBA/.ssh/id_rsa`.  Using the default file name is a good idea because the ssh client will automatically find the key there.

Comment: Thanks I have found that and successfully uploaded my first project to bitbucket.